# Residues of $\frac{e^{z}}{\cos(z)-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I've been working to find the residues of the poles at $2\pi p$ of this function, but I've hit a couple of issues. I've determined that the poles are all of order 2, and from there I've tried directly calculating the first derivative of
$
\varphi(z) = (z-2\pi p)^{2}\frac{e^{z}}{\cos(z)-1}
$
, but that seems to give some real unpleasant expressions that weren't very elegant. Instead, I figured I could factor out a zero of $\cos(z)-1$, which leads me to an expression of the form $\varphi(z) = \frac{e^{z}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(z-2\pi p)^{2n-2}}{(2n)!}}$.

The power series in the denominator here obviously looks a lot like cos(z), and if I could write it as a well-known function it would be easy to find the derivative. Is this a better way to do it? If not, is there another way that simplifies the calculation of the derivative?

Comment: What is the question? To compute the residue at each $z=2k\pi$?

Comment: Yes, I'll make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute the residue at $0$, you can observe that\begin{align}\frac{e^z}{\cos( z)-1}&=\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\cdots}{-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}4-\cdots}\\&=-\frac2{z^2}\cdot\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\cdots}{1-\frac{z^2}2+\cdots}\\&=-\frac2{z^2}(1+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots).\end{align}In order to determine $a_1$, you consider the equality$$1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\cdots=(1+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots)\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\cdots\right),$$from which you deduce that $a_1=1$. Therefore, the residue at $0$ is $-2a_1=-2$.

To compute at a point $2n\pi$, you observe that$$\frac{e^z}{\cos(z)-1}=\frac{e^{2\pi n}e^{z-2\pi n}}{\cos(z-2\pi n)-1},$$and that therefore the residue at $2\pi n$ is $-2e^{2\pi n}$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!